# PHP CodeSniffer start indentation

Tags: php, phpcs

I am looking into setting up the PHPCS to run at build time and report any issues.

Something that I find more readable is a start indentation based on an open PHP tag:

[image]

But PHPCS seems determined that I need to have something like this:

[image]

I understand that this may be a slippery slope and highly biased, but I would very much like to have this particular rule configured.

As a result, I get:

```
 2 | ERROR   | [ ] Missing file doc comment
 3 | ERROR   | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4
 3 | ERROR   | [ ] Expected "if (...) {\n"; found "if (...)\n    {\n"
 3 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 85 characters; contains 94 characters
 3 | ERROR   | [x] There must be a single space between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace of a multi-line IF statement; found newline
 5 | ERROR   | [x] File is being conditionally included; use "include" instead
 5 | WARNING | [ ] Line exceeds 85 characters; contains 89 characters
 6 | ERROR   | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4
```

I am interested in this error in particular:

```
 3 | ERROR   | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected 0 spaces, found 4
```

So far, I have identified that this error came from:

```
/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/src/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/ScopeIndentSniff.php#955
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think it is settings/editor/codestyle/php, then the first tab indents and tabs.

Comment: Nope, I have already fine-tuned IDE's code style, I need PHPCS's sniff configuration